# is there a way I can insert data values when working with postgresql in a python function

Tags: python, postgresql

```
import psycopg2
def connect_table():
    connect= psycopg2.connect("dbname= 'bookshop' user='postgres' password='0973' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cursor= connect.cursor()    
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Title TEXT, Author TEXT, Year INTEGER, ISBN TEXT)")
    connect.commit()     
    connect.close()

def insert(Title,Author,Year,ISBN):
    connect= psycopg2.connect("dbname= 'bookshop' user='postgres' password='0973' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cursor= connect.cursor() 
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO books VALUES (NOT NULL,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (Title,Author,Year,ISBN))
    connect.commit()     
    connect.close()

connect_table()
insert('tears of the sun','robert green',2001,'isb235556')
```

ID is the primary key, so I don't think I need to add it as an argument to the insert function in python. Above is my code, and below is the error I get when I call the insert function..
I would like to find a solution to the error I am getting when I call the insert function in python when adding data values to the books table using postgresql.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/daniel/Desktop/backend.py", line 55, in <module>
    insert('tears of the sun','robert green',2001,'isb235556')
  File "c:/Users/daniel/Desktop/backend.py", line 20, in insert
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO books VALUES (NOT NULL,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (Title,Author,Year,ISBN))
psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type boolean
LINE 1: INSERT INTO books VALUES (NOT NULL,'tears of the sun','rober...
                                  ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Comment: Get rid of the "NOT NULL"; if id is automatically generated you shouldn't pass a value.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` does not show you setting up a `SEQUENCE` or `IDENTITY` on the `id` column so you will need to supply a value for it in your `INSERT`. Or change the table to have to using a `SEQUENCE\IDENTITY` on that column. Then you could do as @snakecharmerb suggested.

Comment: thank you very much Adrian Klaver and snakecharmerb, I used SERIAL in the ID column and got rid of the NOT NULL and it worked...